# Any help on cursor.execute and urljoin?

Tags: python, mysql, scraper

I'm getting:

```
exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

from this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `url` = %s", (urljoin( base_url, item_url ) ))
```

Syntax seems fine - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are passing in a string, where you should be passing in a *tuple*. Note the extra comma at the end:

```
execute("SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `url` = %s", (urljoin(base_url, item_url),))
```